# I'm failing to restore a VirtualBox VM

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to restore a VM but I get this error message:

[image]

I think this happened because, while the VM was live, I removed one snapshot.

How do I fix this, short of restoring older snapshots?

**NOTE**: This problem happens when I use version **4.0.4**. Version **3.2.10** allows me to delete a snapshot of a VM, even though it's live. I guess it's a regression... watch me downgrading.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the situation correctly, then it's quite a severe situation. VirtualBox snapshots are incremental, so later ones depends on earlier ones. When you delete one snapshot VirtualBox does some processing to "merge" the snapshots, that's why it's not very fast to delete a snapshot.

I haven't tried it, but VirtualBox shouldn't let you delete snapshots while the virtual machine is running. In case you somehow managed to do it, I think all hope is lost. I hope you can restore the machine to an earlier snapshot.

Comment: See my updated question.